# Convergence of sequence to minima of convex function

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, convex-analysis

I have a cost function $f$ that is continuous but it might not be smooth. We know that the level set $\{x:f(x)\le f(x^0)\}$ is bounded, and I have an optimization method that generates a sequence $\{x^k\}$ such that $f(x^{k+1})\le f(x^k)$. From this, I know that the sequence $\{x^k\}$ must be bounded, and then it has at least one limit point. My question is: if I additionally assume that the function is convex, then is it guaranteed that the limit point corresponds to a point where $f$ is minimum? Intuitively, I would say yes, but I'm not sure if how I can prove it. 
Any comments on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not sufficient. Take, e.g., $f(x) = x^2$ on the real line and $x^k = 1 + 1/k$.

Comment: (or even just $x^k=1$ for all $k$...)

Comment: @charlestoncrabb: This was also my first thought, but in my example, you actually have even $f(x^{k+1}) < f(x^k)$ and still no convergence.

Comment: True, and a convex function need not even _have_ a minimum: $e^x$, e.g. (edit: in this case the sub-level set is unbounded...)

Comment: Oh, I see. That was kind of obvious. Then what I have to prove is that, under the appropriate assumptions, $f(x^k)$ approaches $f^*$ as $k$ tends to infinity. Thank you guys for the comments!